# SmtpClient sends email to junk

Tags: c#, email, smtp

I tried to send email from c# using SmtpClient.Send() but it always goes to the junk box. It works fine if I send it from Outlook. Is there anyway to solve this? Someone told me to modify the email header but I don't know how.
Thanks in advance.
Here is my code

```
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
client.Host = "smtp.server.com";
client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("user", "password");
MailAddress mailFrom = new MailAddress("mymail@server.com");
MailAddress mailTo = new MailAddress("yourmail@server.com");
MailAddress mailReply = new MailAddress("mymail@server.com");
MailMessage message = new MailMessage(mailFrom, mailTo);
message.Body = "This is a test message.";
message.Subject = "test message";
message.SubjectEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
message.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
client.Send(message);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a) The code sample doesn't actually use the mailReply address.

b) The problem will probably disappear when you send a more realistic message. If it doesn't then you will have to find out why the message is being marked junk, fishing a message from the spambox and looking at the headers or something like that.

Comment: lolz, you're right! the mailReply instance is not getting referenced/used by anything :)

Answer (score 1):

Spam filters may discard messages that have invalid entries.

Try putting in valid (existing) addresses of sender, reply and from.